# unique_ptr .release & .reset unexpected deleter behavior

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I'm experimenting with smart pointers and experiencing a problem with the `unique_ptr`. What sparked this is that in VS2013 I am using `.release()` in a class destructor and it's not releasing (using `TRACE`) yet it is with `.reset`. 
I have some sample code at the following URL: [IDEOne Example Code](http://ideone.com/0aWEzj)

I've created a class containing two `unique_ptr` members. These members get assigned in the constructor and in theory, according to smart pointer theory as I understand it, should get `delete`d automatically. They are assigned a custom struct as a custom deleter, as defined below:

```
struct Deleter
    {
    void operator()(TCHAR* p) const
    {
        std::cout << "Deleter deleting .." << p << '\n';
        delete[] p;
    }
};
```

The `unique_ptr` members are declared as:

```
unique_ptr<TCHAR[], Deleter> szMySimpleString;
unique_ptr<TCHAR[], Deleter> szMySimpleStringLeak;
```

the `unique_ptr` members are then defined in the constructor of a class as:

```
    szMySimpleString = unique_ptr<TCHAR[], Deleter>(new TCHAR[255], Deleter());
    szMySimpleStringLeak = unique_ptr<TCHAR[], Deleter>(new TCHAR[255], Deleter());
    strcpy(this->szMySimpleString.get(), "szMySimpleString");
    strcpy(this->szMySimpleStringLeak.get(), "szMySimpleStringLeak");
```

When this class is deleted, I have the destructor running `.release()` in one example, `.reset()` in another. Each has behavior that I wouldn't expect. `.release()` is running the deleter on the wrong `unique_ptr` while `.reset` runs the deleter on both `unique_ptr`'s.

Please see the full code at the link at the beginning of this question (Note: There are 3 commented-out areas to run one at a time to see each effect).

If I run:

```
szMySimpleStringLeak.release();
```

I get the results:

```
    Doing Stuff ...
    Contents of szMySimpleString: szMySimpleString
    Contents of szMySimpleStringLeak: szMySimpleStringLeak

    MyStupidClass Destructor running...
    Deleter deleting ..szMySimpleString
```

If I run:

```
szMySimpleString.release();
```

I get the results:

```
Deleter deleting ..szMySimpleStringLeak
```

and if I run:

```
szMySimpleString.reset();
```

I get the results:

```
    MyStupidClass Destructor running...
    Deleter deleting ..szMySimpleString
    Deleter deleting ..szMySimpleStringLeak
```

I'd appreciate any input to why this behavior is unexpected (or rather why I should expect it).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`unique_ptr::release`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) relinquishes ownership of the managed object without destroying it. [`unique_ptr::reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) will destroy the object using the supplied deleter.

It's not that calling `release()` is running the deleter on the wrong `unique_ptr` instance, but that it's not running the deleter on the instance on which you called `release()`. The deleter for the other instance is automatically called by the `unique_ptr`'s destructor, which is implicitly invoked by your class' destructor.

If you leave the `unique_ptr` instances alone, and called neither `reset()` nor `release()` on either of them, then you'll see the expected behavior when your class' destructor executes.

Answer (score 1):

`unique_ptr::release()` does not delete the internal pointer, instead it releases the *ownership* of it. [See the doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release).

So in your case calling `release()` just causes memory leak.